# How to check if an id exists as the child of instance class?

Tags: python, button, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

So I have a problem that I want to check that if an image exists inside a button and I have created a dictionary containing all the ids of the 16 images. I have a total of 64 buttons and only 16 contain images so I have created a function that checks if any of the ids in the dictionary are inside the button object (instance.children). Below is some of my .kv code:

```
 Button:
        id: button_1
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: (1,1,1,1)
        on_press: root.moves(self, root)

        AsyncImage:
            id: white_1
            source: 'imgs/WhiteCastle.png'
            center_x: self.parent.center_x
            center_y: self.parent.center_y

    Button:
        id: button_2
        background_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
        on_press: root.moves(self, root)

        AsyncImage:
            id: white_2
            source: 'imgs/WhiteKnight.png'
            center_x: self.parent.center_x
            center_y: self.parent.center_y

    Button:
        id: button_3
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: (1,1,1,1)
        on_press: root.moves(self, root)

        AsyncImage:
            id: white_3
            source: 'imgs/WhiteBishop.png'
            center_x: self.parent.center_x
            center_y: self.parent.center_y
```

And now here is my .py code:

```
def img_list(self):
    img_ids_list = []

    for x in range(1, 17):
        img_ids_list.append(f"white_{x}")

    for y in range(1, 17):
        img_ids_list.append(f"black_{y}")

    return img_ids_list

def moves(self, instance, root):
    all_ids = root.ids
    id_of_button = self.get_id(instance)
    img_id = self.check_if_img_exists(instance, root)

def check_if_img_exists(self, instance, root):
    img_ids = self.img_list()

    if img_ids[0] in root.ids:
        print("Ready for launch!")
        for x in img_ids:
            asyncImage = root.ids.image_ids[x]
            if asyncImage in instance.children:
                print("Button contains an AsyncImage")

    print("Button does not contain an AsyncImage")

def get_id(self, instance):
    for id, widget in instance.parent.parent.ids.items():
        if widget.__self__ == instance:
            return id
```

Can someone plzz help.

Comment: "can someone plzz help" is not a question. What's wrong with what you have? What should it do, and what is it doing instead?

Comment: `check_if_img_exists()` isn't returning anything. You need a `return` statement somewhere.

Comment: Maybe `return x` after the `print()` statement when it finds a match.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot, the function is returning:  'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'

Comment: return is not working Barmar